# javascript cant get index number of data-index

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

When I console.log(currentIndex), there just comes NaN.
What should I do?
I can't get any fixes about data-index.
Can I even use data-index for this?

```js
$(".element").mouseover(()=> {
  var currentIndex = parseInt($(this).data('index'));
  console.log(currentIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i class="element" data-index="0">0</i>
<i class="element" data-index="1">1</i>
<i class="element" data-index="2">2</i>
<i class="element" data-index="3">3</i>
<i class="element" data-index="4">4</i>
```

Comment: because all of this ".element" are EMPTY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *This* isn't what you expect.

When you use a fat arrow function `() => {}` you say that 'this' shouldn't switch into your local context. By using a classic `function` style, you set `this` to the expected element and it works.

```js
$(".element").mouseover(function()  {

  var currentIndex = parseInt($(this).data('index'));
  console.log(currentIndex);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="element" data-index="0">0</i>
<i class="element" data-index="1">1</i>
<i class="element" data-index="2">2</i>
<i class="element" data-index="3">3</i>
<i class="element" data-index="4">4</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".element").mouseover((e) => {

  var currentIndex = parseInt($(e.target).data('index'));
  console.log(currentIndex);

});
```